# Bitbake list of targets

Tags: yocto, bitbake

thx for reading,
I am working in a project where we create a secimage (linux yocto image).

I am not familiar with all the tools used there and neither am I familiar with the technical terms to use. So this question may be just really really stupid, but I cannot figure it out by the life of mine.

We have a YOCTO ...something... with all those recipes (debian packages) we need on our (resulting) Operating-System, we use (don't know if this is obvious) bitbake to build our Image.

I know that we have some ...targets... for the bitbake command (e.g. a target for building the image for production and a target for building the image for development purposes, they obviously differ in the packages installed, just to mention one: gdb-server).

Since I came into this project later on, I have no idea how they named those targets... so I just want to know:

How can I get a list of **targets**?

(I tried searching but since I am not even familiar with all the technical terms to use, cause I am not a developer for YOCTO, I may just did not search for the right terms)

I do **not** want to list the **tasks**, I just want to make a development image, which I know there is a target configured for it, I just don't know its name (and none of my colleges are here, nor will they be any time soon).

### EDIT

Davids answer seems to be the closest, but there are some other ways in the comments ;-). THX all for your help, appreciated.

Comment: Nevermind, I just did a `grep -rnw #theOneTargetNameIKnew#` and got a (lot of) result(s) pointing me to
/#YOCTO#/#OurDistroMetaDirectory#/recipes-core/images/#target#.bb.

Those seem to be the targets. If anyone has a bitbake command to get a list of these though, that would be nice. THX

Comment: Check out the [Yocto Mega Manual - Chapter 27. Images](http://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/2.1/mega-manual/mega-manual.html#ref-images) section to understand what an output target is. Generally each image should be placed in meta layer within image directory in corresponding _image_name_.bb recipe. As pointed in linked chapter, instead of grepping through whole workspace, you can examine your meta layers by calling: `  $ ls meta*/recipes*/images/*.bb`. Have fun using yocto!

Comment: So there is defenitly no command in the bitbake binaries!?... *shakes his head out of disappointment*... Yeah that command works, thx... a little tweak ;-) : `ls meta*/recipes*/images/*.bb | sed -e 's/^.*\///g' | sed -e 's/\.bb$//g'`--- Just seeing, it's in @h0ch5tr4355 caommand too...

Comment: Oh,  and a big thx for the mega-manual... didn't find that yet (sure am glad I dont need to work on the YOCTO images)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can easily list all the targets/recipes (.bb files) in your workspace doing:

```
bitbake-layers show-recipes
```

If you want only the recipes for your image, do:

```
bitbake-layers show-recipes "<image_name>"
```

Comment: This is a list of recipes only though, not a list of images per se. So it's not really what I want, but if it is known that the images one is looking for have a specific prefix/infix/postfix, the second command given can be useful. (If anyone is having troubles with the above, remember to set up the environment `source oe-init-build-env`. ) THX David

Comment: I'd like you to include the limitation of this answer in your post (prefix/infix/postfix) but as h0ch5tr4355 I too think this is the closest answer (as long as there really ain't a way to find images only with one command, but it doesn't look like it). I will accept this. THX

Comment: You can two ways as bitbake doesn't make differences for recipes: Either the assumption that image-recipes are always in `images`folders or te assumption that  `image`is in the name of the recipe. second would also give this command: `bitbake-layers show-recipes "*-image-*"`

Answer (score 9):

To list the pre-defined Yocto images, run the following command from your `poky` directory

```
ls meta*/recipes*/images/*.bb
```

Comment: This is the correct answer according to the yocto manual:
https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/1.8/ref-manual/ref-manual.html#ref-images

Answer (score 4):

Other SDKs often use a custom script for setting up the build environment for yocto (mostly refers on `oe-init-build-env` from yocto anyway).

I took an excerpt of the setup script from the Freescale SDK 1.9 (`fsl-setup-env`) and created a script to display the images. It can be similar to this:

`get-images.sh`:

```
# top level directory of your yocto project
POKYROOTDIR=/home/poky

echo "Images:"
for i in `ls $POKYROOTDIR/meta*/recipes-*/images/*.bb 2>/dev/null`;do
    i=`basename $i`;i=`echo $i |sed -e 's,^\(.*\)\.bb,\1,'`
    echo "    $i";
done
```

This is based on the assumption that every recipe is placed in a `images` directory, what is supposed to be a convention.

Comment: Also look at iksajotien's solution in the comments which is the short version of this

Comment: I always forget that i have to escape the braces in sed, this is nice, but not a bitbake command, i see that i didnt explicitly asked for a bitbale command, but i am gonn await out to see if someone knows a bitbake command for this. thx

Comment: deleted my comment and overworked it in David Bensoussan's solution.

Comment: Better to make the POKYROOTDIR var generic and get the path using pwd, like so POKYROOTDIR=`pwd`;

Answer (score 4):

To list the pre-defined Yocto images in all meta files, run the following command from your poky directory

```
find . -type f -path '*images/*' -name '*.bb'
```

Answer (score 3):

A similar command as the one provided on the NXP website [here](https://community.nxp.com/t5/i-MX-Processors-Knowledge-Base/Useful-bitbake-commands/ta-p/1128559)

```
bitbake-layers show-recipes "*image*"
```

Answer (score 0):

I like this solution:

```
ziga@ziga--hypervisor:~/yocto$ ag -g .bb poky/meta | grep image

poky/meta/recipes-sato/images/core-image-sato.bb
poky/meta/recipes-sato/images/core-image-sato-dev.bb
poky/meta/recipes-sato/images/core-image-sato-sdk.bb
poky/meta/recipes-sato/images/core-image-sato-ptest-fast.bb
poky/meta/recipes-sato/images/core-image-sato-sdk-ptest.bb
poky/meta/recipes-graphics/xorg-lib/xcb-util-image_0.4.0.bb
poky/meta/recipes-graphics/images/core-image-clutter.bb
poky/meta/recipes-graphics/images/core-image-x11.bb
poky/meta/recipes-graphics/images/core-image-weston.bb
poky/meta/recipes-rt/images/core-image-rt-sdk.bb
poky/meta/recipes-rt/images/core-image-rt.bb
poky/meta/classes/image-live.bbclass
poky/meta/classes/kernel-uimage.bbclass
poky/meta/classes/image-combined-dbg.bbclass
poky/meta/classes/testimage.bbclass
poky/meta/classes/license_image.bbclass
poky/meta/classes/image-postinst-intercepts.bbclass
poky/meta/classes/core-image.bbclass
poky/meta/classes/image-mklibs.bbclass
poky/meta/classes/image-prelink.bbclass
poky/meta/classes/image_types_wic.bbclass
poky/meta/classes/image-buildinfo.bbclass
poky/meta/classes/image_types.bbclass
poky/meta/classes/kernel-fitimage.bbclass
poky/meta/classes/image.bbclass
poky/meta/classes/image-container.bbclass
poky/meta/recipes-extended/images/core-image-testmaster.bb
poky/meta/recipes-extended/images/core-image-testmaster-initramfs.bb
poky/meta/recipes-extended/images/core-image-kernel-dev.bb
poky/meta/recipes-extended/images/core-image-full-cmdline.bb
poky/meta/recipes-core/ovmf/ovmf-shell-image.bb
poky/meta/recipes-core/images/core-image-minimal-mtdutils.bb
poky/meta/recipes-core/images/core-image-minimal.bb
poky/meta/recipes-core/images/core-image-base.bb
poky/meta/recipes-core/images/core-image-minimal-initramfs.bb
poky/meta/recipes-core/images/core-image-minimal-dev.bb
poky/meta/recipes-core/images/core-image-tiny-initramfs.bb
poky/meta/recipes-core/images/build-appliance-image_15.0.0.bb
```